# Objective C - Create modal Segue

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, modal-dialog

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to use the Storyboard correctly. My main issue being Modal segues. I have a viewcontroller which I'm trying to display modally (far right in image below). But it just isn't showing. The prepareForSegue is firing correctly.

It does work when I change the segue from a Modal to a Push though.

I'm calling the segue using

```
performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FirstRunSegue" sender:self
```

Here is the visual segue setup I have at the moment

[image]

When I hover over the Excaimation mark, the following error is displayed:

[image]

I am kind of new to Storyboarding, so I'm hoping that someone could explain why the modal segue isn't working and how I would get it to work. The nasty thing is that it is a requirement for the viewcontroller to be in the Storyboard, otherwise I'd just initialize the controller and display it manually.

Regards,
EZfrag

Edit 1:

OK, I managed to figure out why the segue is not being displayed. It is kind of stupid, because it works for a push. It seems that I cannot call a modal segue from the appdeletegate's startup function. Push works fine, but not modal. Confirmed it with a new project.

Is there someone that can explain why this is so?

Regards,
EZFrag

Comment: Can you expand more on the flow of the application?  It sounds like your initial VC is the one that is calling the modally presented VC, and that is only supposed to happen on first load.  Is that correct?  If so, where are you calling performSegue?

Comment: How do you "fire" the segue - via storyboard or by code?

Comment: By code:
'performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FirstRunSegue" sender:self' where self is the owner of the segue.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the push segue with a `UINavigationController`, but it looks like you are trying to use it between two regular `UIViewContoller`. If you want to change the way the animation looks, use a custom segue and write your own transition.

Comment: Not correct.  You can use a modal segue with a navigation controller.

Comment: Ok, I changed my wording. I meant that if you are using a push segue, then you must use a UINavigationController. But, yes, you can use other segues with a UINavigationController also.

Comment: EZFrag, did you try the custom segue?

Comment: It is not the animation that I want to change... I just need the modal segue to do what it is supposed to do... to display a modal view.